# Change multiple png sprite file color to another color

Tags: gimp, png, color-conversion, image-sprite

I have a sprite of 100 png files. This sprite file contains two colors only. Grey and blue.
Which software or application would someone recommend where i can rapidly change the two colors of these png files to another colors?
I have to perform this tasks multiple times in a week for a month. Just to get verification from personnels.

I tried importing into GIMP, using layer. But, i do not see any function in GIMP where it allow me to convert the colors when all layers are visible. I still have to select them one by one.

Also, keep in mind. after changing the colors, i would like to have a separate 100 png files. Not all merge into a gif.

Really hope to hear from gurus!

[image: png sprites]

Comment: Spidersense tingling. Seems to me that you are solving the wrong problem with the wrong tool, wrong approach and wrong idea. Whats exactly wrong in rasterizing the data again. Its simpler faster and more flexible. This is not meant in any bad way.

Answer (score 2):

Given the small size, I would use the [`ofn-tiles` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) to load them all in a single flat layer, apply the change to the layer, and then use the export function of the same script to chop the layers to tiles and export them to individual files. The script lets you specify a naming scheme to load/save tiles so you could even be so lucky you wouldn't need to rename files later.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Assuming the gray is really gray, you could see if changing the Hue is good enough to have the colors you need. This will only change the blue (saturated) color. So prepare a batch process to change the hue.

This would work well in case you do not actually have only two colors, but a series of tiny intermediate colors for the anti-aliasing.

**2.** I am not an expert in Gimp, but a script selecting color range would help you mask by color and apply different changes, not only in hue but on saturation for example.